# I can't start Ubuntu, GRUB does not appear

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a problem trying to get to Ubuntu. I installed as usual: first, I took some space from Windows, then started Ubuntu from usb, selected **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**, finished installation, but when I restart my computer GRUB does not appear, and it goes directly to Windows and there's no other way to start Ubuntu.

I've tried all the solutions I found on the internet, but I've run out of options. I tried:

- boot-repair from a live USB
- Changing boot path from Windows cmd (`bcdedit`)
- Tried with the Ubuntu terminal `efibootmanager` from live USB
- I made sure that installation was in UEFI mode (same as Windows)
- I disabled secure boot from BIOS
- I disabled Windows fast start

I don't know if it's useful information, but I'm trying this in my laptop, which is a Lenovo Thinkpad e560, Intel i7, 16GB RAM, 500 GB disk, running Windows 10 home.

I hope you have some more solutions to try :)